# Precision of BigInt JavaScript type

Tags: javascript, bigint

I have such part of code, where `s1` is a correct binary number (string, up to 900 characters):

```
console.log(BigInt('0b' + s1));
console.log(toLong10(s1));
```

```
25153017620665555630531113...
25153017620663410729799174...
```

These two functions give different results. Which of them is more likely to be wrong: does BigInt really lose so much precision or is it more realistic that I have a mistake in my function?

```
function summarize(a, b)
{
        while(b.length < a.length)
            b = "0" + b;
        while(a.length < b.length)
            a = "0" + a;
        a = "0" + a;
        b = "0" + b;
        let extra = 0;
        let i = a.length - 1;
        let res = "";
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            let tmp = Number(a[i]) + Number(b[i]) + extra;
            extra = Math.floor(tmp / 10);
            tmp = tmp % 10;
            res = tmp.toString() + res;
            i--;
        }
        if (res[0] == '0')
        {
            res = res.substr(1);
        }
        return(res);
}
function multiply2(a, b)
{
        a = "0" + a;
        let res = "";
        let extra = 0;
        for (let i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            let tmp = b * a[i] + extra;
            extra = Math.floor(tmp / 10);
            tmp = tmp % 10;
            res = tmp.toString() + res;
        }
        if (res[0] == '0')
        {
            res = res.substr(1);
        }
        return(res);
}
function multiply(a, b)
{
        let res = "0";
        if (b.length > a.length)
        {
            let c = a;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
        let extra0 = "";
        for (let i = b.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            res = summarize(res, multiply2(a, b[i]) + extra0);
            extra0 = extra0 + "0";
        }
        if (res[0] == '0')
        {
            res = res.substr(1);
        }
        return(res);
}
function toPower(num, power)
{
    let res = "1";
    if (power == 0)
        return(res);
    res = toPower(num, Math.floor(power / 2));
    if (power % 2 == 0)
        return(multiply(res, res));
    else
        return(multiply(multiply(res, res), num));
}
function toLong10(a)
{
    a = a.split("").reverse().join("");
    let res = "0";
    let power = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        res = summarize(res, multiply(a[i], toPower("2", power)));
        power++;
    }
    return(res);
}
```

Comment: What is `toLong10()`?

Comment: Without knowing what `toLong10()` is, nobody can help.  The `BigInt` type has unbounded (except by raw memory availability) precision.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]; in this case, the value of `s1` that produces the results shown, and the function `toLong10`.

Comment: Ok, I will add the toLong10 function. It is rather big, so I thought it will be possible to estimate the precision of Bigint and decide, whether it gives correct result

Comment: Again, `BigInt` has unbounded precision. If you expect the two results to be the same, and they're not, that means `toLong10()` is incorrect.

Comment: here it is, I added it

Comment: In general, if the question is whether a popular library has a serious bug or you have a bug in your own code, it's vastly more likely that you have a bug. So it sounds like you're asking us to debug your code.

Comment: I have read that BigInt usually loses precision. And the question is about: how much precision does it lose? Does this differense in two numbers given to me by the program seem to be inside the inaccuracy of BigInt type

Comment: @ALEX Where have you read that? No, it does not.

Comment: You read something with incorrect statements.

Comment: ok. Than mistake is of course in my code. Thanks.

Comment: You probably misunderstand. You'll lose precision if you convert a BigInt to a Number.

Comment: Provide an example `s1`.  Does your example the results of either statement?  If so, which one?

Comment: As I said, it is rather large. So it is hard to post it here) But I understood, thanks. I will try to fuind a mistake in my code

Comment: Unbounded precision arithmetic is a well-understood technology, there have been libraries for it for decades (it was built into Lisp at least as long ago as the 70's). It's almost inconceivable that the JavaScript BigInt code would have a serious error like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am in process of finding a mistake now)